# skip failed activity in azure data factory and proceed to next activity

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

We have a requirement where if any activity fails in a pipeline then it should not hamper the rest of the activities and it should proceed further with the rest of the activity

```
{
    "name": "pipeline1",
    "properties": {
        "description": "pipeline1",
        "activities": [
            {
                "name": "PipelineName Lookup",
                "type": "Lookup",
                "dependsOn": [],
                "policy": {
                    "timeout": "7.00:00:00",
                    "retry": 0,
                    "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "source": {
                        "type": "AzureSqlSource",
                        "sqlReaderQuery": {
                            "value": "select cast(1 as bit)",
                            "type": "Expression"
                        },
                        "queryTimeout": "02:00:00",
                        "partitionOption": "None"
                    },
                    "dataset": {
                        "referenceName": "AzureSqlTable1",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "If Condition1",
                "type": "IfCondition",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "PipelineName Lookup",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Completed"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "expression": {
                        "value": "@equals(activity('PipelineName Lookup').output,True)",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    },
                    "ifFalseActivities": [
                        {
                            "name": "Lookup1_copy1",
                            "type": "Lookup",
                            "dependsOn": [],
                            "policy": {
                                "timeout": "7.00:00:00",
                                "retry": 0,
                                "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                                "secureOutput": false,
                                "secureInput": false
                            },
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "source": {
                                    "type": "AzureSqlSource",
                                    "sqlReaderQuery": "Select 1",
                                    "queryTimeout": "02:00:00",
                                    "partitionOption": "None"
                                },
                                "dataset": {
                                    "referenceName": "AzureSqlTable3",
                                    "type": "DatasetReference"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    "ifTrueActivities": [
                        {
                            "name": "Lookup1",
                            "type": "Lookup",
                            "dependsOn": [],
                            "policy": {
                                "timeout": "7.00:00:00",
                                "retry": 0,
                                "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                                "secureOutput": false,
                                "secureInput": false
                            },
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "source": {
                                    "type": "AzureSqlSource",
                                    "sqlReaderQuery": "Select 1",
                                    "queryTimeout": "02:00:00",
                                    "partitionOption": "None"
                                },
                                "dataset": {
                                    "referenceName": "AzureSqlTable3",
                                    "type": "DatasetReference"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ],
        "annotations": []
    }
}
```

I am using the above code but i dont think that is working for my requirement. What we are actually looking for is a design where in we if any activity is failing then it should skip the failed activity and proceed further with the remaining activity. I would request for some help

Answer (score 0):

Make the dependency 'completed' not 'success' ... click on the plus in a circle to get the dropdown, like this ...

[image]

... then link to your next activity

[image]

The arrows linking the activities are not a flow, they are showing dependencies ... so here the lookup is dependent only on the copy completing (success or fail) rather than on it having to succeed (the default).

Hope that makes sense!